# Unexpected type error when using Typescript's type intersections with discriminated unions

Tags: typescript

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Discriminant1_False%20%7B%20discriminant_1%3A%20false%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Discriminant1_True%20%7B%20discriminant_1%3A%20true%2C%20extra_field_1%3A%20boolean%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Discriminant1%20%3D%20Discriminant1_True%20%7C%20Discriminant1_False%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Discriminant2_False%20%7B%20discriminant_2%3A%20false%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20Discriminant2_True%20%7B%20discriminant_2%3A%20true%2C%20extra_field_2%3A%20boolean%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Discriminant2%20%3D%20Discriminant2_True%20%7C%20Discriminant2_False%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FullType%20%3D%20Discriminant1%20%26%20Discriminant2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20type_which_generates_erroneous_error_message%3A%20FullType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20discriminant_1%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20discriminant_2%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

I am running what seems to be an incorrect type error when trying to use Typescript's type intersections and discriminated unions together.

The idea is:

An object should contain two booleans - `discriminant_1` and `discriminant_2`. If either of these discriminant fields is `true`, the object should contain an extra field - `extra_field_1` and `extra_field_2` respectively.

So here are some examples of valid objects:

```
// Neither field is true - no extra fields
{ discriminant_1: false, discriminant_2: false }

// discriminant_1 is true - extra_field_1 present
{ discriminant_1: true, extra_field_1: true, discriminant_2: false }

// both discriminant fields are true - both extra fields present
{ discriminant_1: true, extra_field_1: true, discriminant_2: true, extra_field_2: true }
```

And an invalid object, because `discriminant_2` is `true` but `extra_field_2` is missing

```
{ discriminant_1: false, discriminant_2: true }
```

This provides compilation errors in the expected places, but those errors are confusing in instances where fields are not provided.

For the following object:

```
{ discriminant_1: false, discriminant_2: true }
```

The type does not compile because if `discriminant_2` is `true`, `extra_field_2` should be specified in the object. But the type error is:

```
Type '{ discriminant_1: false; discriminant_2: true; }' is not assignable to type 'FullType'.
  Type '{ discriminant_1: false; discriminant_2: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Discriminant1_True & Discriminant2_True'.
    Property 'extra_field_1' is missing in type '{ discriminant_1: false; discriminant_2: true; }' but required in type 'Discriminant1_True'.
```

The error message implies that the type that is inferred is `Discriminant1_True & Discriminant2_True` despite the fact that `discriminant_1` is `false`, and says that `extra_field_1` is missing when in fact it is `extra_field_2` that is missing.

The expected error message is:

```
Type '{ discriminant_1: false; discriminant_2: true; }' is not assignable to type 'FullType'.
  Type '{ discriminant_1: false; discriminant_2: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Discriminant1_False & Discriminant2_True'.
    Property 'extra_field_2' is missing in type '{ discriminant_1: false; discriminant_2: true; }' but required in type 'Discriminant2_True'.
```

Which would point the programmer towards the correct missing field.

Is it possible to write the types in such a way that the error messages that are returned when constructing erroneous types point towards the correct missing field?

Comment: You should search GitHub for a similar issue, I don't think SO is a good place for this question. The behavior is indeed what you describe. If you add the correct fields it works, it's just the error message that is a wonky. My guess is that since there are multiple possible discriminants typescript just picks the first member of the union and generates errors for that one even though the object might be closer to another type in the union.

Comment: Thanks Titian! I did have a look at Github but couldn't find a related issue - however someone pointed me towards [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30648) which as far as I can tell details the same problem

Comment: yeah, that looks like the exact one. I was sure there was a similar issue :). It's in the backlog so it might get fixed at some point, although I suspect it does not have a high priority

Answer (score 0):

Let me give my 2 cents and hopefully someone far wiser than me (*coff* @basarat ) can tell you even more cool stuff :-)

I'm not sure that discriminated unions quite give you what you're after here.  User defined type guards may.  Let me explain.  Your object is roughly like this:

```
interface NotTheTypeSafetyYouHopedFor { 
    discriminant_1: boolean; 
    extra_field_1?: boolean; 
    discriminant_2: boolean; 
    extra_field_2?: boolean; 
}
```

But you'd like to enforce the types a little more.  So let's simplify the problem by forgetting that `discriminant_2` and `extra_field_2?` exist.  Poof! They're gone.

```
interface False1 { 
    discriminant_1: false; 
}

interface True1 { 
    discriminant_1: true; 
    extra_field_1: boolean; 
}

type False1OrTrue1 = False1 | True1;

const exampleFalse1: False1 = { discriminant_1: false };
const exampleTrue1: True1 = { discriminant_1: true, extra_field_1: false };


function isTrue1(aFalse1OrTrue1: False1OrTrue1): aFalse1OrTrue1 is True1 { 
    return aFalse1OrTrue1.hasOwnProperty('extra_field_1')
}


function doSomething(aFalse1OrTrue1: False1OrTrue1) { 
    if (isTrue1(aFalse1OrTrue1)) {
        console.log(aFalse1OrTrue1.extra_field_1); // succeeds as this is a True1 
    } else { 
        console.log(aFalse1OrTrue1.extra_field_1); // compile error as this is a False1 
    }
}
```

I suspect that this an approach which may not scale directly given the nature of your question (i.e. discriminant_2 etc)

But if each property in an object was a `False1OrTrue1` then perhaps it would suit your needs?  Hope that helps.  Guida says "hi" :-)

Comment: The problem is not with the functionality of the type. The type functions as the OP expects, it lets objects OP thinks valid pass, and errors on objects OP thinks invalid (al least in my reading, OP feel free to correct me on this). The only issue is that the error message for certain invalid objects appears to be confusing. The error should be there, just the message is the problem \

Comment: Thanks John! I haven't used user-defined type guards much so it's cool to see a use case for them. Unfortunately I don't think it will work for my case. My actual code has three string-union discriminants, each with their own set of values and each of which determines a different set of fields on the final object.

The code actually does work, i.e. it compiles/doesn't compile when the object is valid/invalid. It's just the error messages in the invalid case don't seem correct. Someone pointed me to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30648) which looks related

Comment: Happy to try to help! It looks like that GitHub issue is super relevant. Nice to see the Type-Fu you're attempting; type systems are *addictive* 